# lightgallery dynamic. Add alt attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I generate a lightgallery using the following dynamic script. Everything works as it should.

```js
defer(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lightgallery").on('click', function() {
      $(this).lightGallery({
        dynamic: true,
        dynamicEl: [
          @foreach(var photo in Model.Photos) {

            @: {
              "src": '@Url.Action("GetPhoto", "Photo", new { photoId = photo.Id, photoName = photo.Name })',
              'thumb': '@Url.Action("GetPhotoThumbnail", "Photo", new { photoId = photo.Id, photoName = photo.Name })'
            },
          }
        ]
      });
    })
  })
});
```

Now I need to add the attribute "alt" to each photos. in the core of the lightgallery this is probably not. How to do it? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This is a wild guess, but have you tried adding `"alt": contents_of_alt` to the same object where you specify `"src`"?  Without glancing at documentation that's what I would expect intuitively. But I'm not familiar with lightGallery so if that didn't work on the first try I'd head to the docs.

Comment: @TrevorReid 
Yes, of course, I tried) This option unfortunately does not work. 
Documentation all investigated a hundred times. The only thought that came is to do it somehow through jquery. but all my attempts were a failure(